# How can I disable CORS for a single route in Express without rewriting all of my routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

TLDR: In the example, I just want to make it so that `/users/delete` cannot be called by anything outside of my React app.

I have a bunch of routes for the backend API of my app that uses Express:

#### ie. server.js

```
app.get('/invoices/read', async (req, res) => {
    // gather data from db
    res.json({...data})
})
```

I have cors enabled globally like so:

#### server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});
```

So, my question is, how would I disable CORS for a single route such as this

```
app.post('/users/delete', async (req, res) => {
    // delete user out of database
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

without rewriting all of my routes to something like this:

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.get('/invoices/read', cors(), async (req, res) => {
    // gather data from db
    res.json({...data})
})
```

So that a user can't just make a POST request to `/users/delete` using an arbitrary ID in an attempt to delete a user out of my system?

> Do I need to just include the origin in my headers or do I need to disable CORS for that route?

- In the past, I've had trouble getting a string of origins to work using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Just put the one route BEFORE your middleware that enables CORS.  Then, the CORS headers will not be present when serving that route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override the header only on the route you want to "disable" it:

```js
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'alloweddomain.com')
```

If you need to allow more than one domain, you can make a list of allowed domains and check if the origin is included there:

```js
const allowedDomains = ['allowedomain1.com', 'alloweddomain2.com'];
const origin = req.get('origin');

if (allowedDomains.includes(origin)) {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
}
```

Comment: And I can include multiple domains by supplying multiple domains to that string separated by a space?

Comment: @ihodonald yes. You can also use wildcards like `*` (any domain) or `*.domain.com` (any subdomain), etc.

Comment: @Cartucho I thought wildcard cors were not allowed?

Comment: Does above solution works for only "GET" request?

Answer (score 5):

One other solution I've found:

On the global invocation of `app.use(cors())`, you can add the option `preflightContinue: true`, and that should allow follow-up middleware on the specific page to override it.

**In the top-level config**

```
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: 'http://localhost:9001',
      // Allow follow-up middleware to override this CORS for options
      preflightContinue: true,
    }),
  );
```

**In my specific route declaration**

```
router.options('/myRoute', cors(myRouteOptions));
router.post(
  '/myRoute',
  cors(myRouteOptions),
  async (req, res) => {
    // ...
  },
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `cors()` middleware for the `OPTIONS` method like I did. Above works but also possible to pass cors in an `all()` first `.all(cors(opts)).get(yourMiddleware())`

Answer (score 1):

Using Express router and `cors` module:

```
// Define the router 
const v1 = express.Router();

// Initiate express app
const api = express();

 const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: [],
    allowedHeaders: [],
    exposedHeaders: [],
    credentials: true
};

// Define subroutes here 
v1.get('/list', (req, res) => { // action implementation here})

// Define cors per route 
v1.all('/list', cors(corsOptions));

// Add the router to express  
api.use('/', v1);
```

Or using a cors middleware

```
v1.get('/list',  cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => { // action implementation here})
```

Both should work, I hope this helps.

Comment: This would work if I wanted to rewrite all of the routes, but now, with hundreds of routes defined in my middleware, it's going to be hard for me to rewrite all of them since some of them actually already contain middleware. @Felipe's answer provides a way of disabling CORS only for single routes. 

TLDR: Thank you, I will use this method (supplying CORS to the route) going forward.

Comment: I still haven't tested it yet, so I'm still open to suggestions.